# How to get a callback when the specified epoch number is over?

Tags: python, keras

I want to fine turn my model when using Keras, and I want to change my training data and learning rate to train when the epochs arrive 10, So how to get a callback when the specified epoch number is over.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own Callback subclass.

https://keras.io/callbacks/ (general information)

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L275 (source code for the Callback base class)

Your Callback subclass should define an `on_epoch_end()` method, which accepts the epoch number as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the way keras works this is probably not the best way to go, it would be much better to treat this as fine tuning, meaning that you finish the 10 epochs, save the model and then load the model (from another script) and continue training with the lr and data you fancy.

There are several reasons for this.

1. It is much clearer and easier to debug. You check you model properly after the 10 epochs, verify that it works properly and carry on
2. It is much better to do several experiments this way, starting from epoch 10.

Good luck!